# Defined Variable as a reference in an Offset Range

Tags: vba, variables, offset

I have run into trouble writing a code in VBA that will allow me to describe a range of non-consecutive cells when one of those cells is a variable. When I run this line of code I get an error at the line beginning with `Range(copyToRange) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(copyFromRange)`. Sorry if this is a simple fix, I've been banging my head against a wall all day:

```
Sub GetPCData()

'Get PC response ratios

PCanalytes = Array("Furosemide", "Caffeine", "Ketoprofen", "Phenylbutazone", "Flunixin")
PCanalytePositions = Array("J32", "J33", "J34", "J35", "J36")

Set SQWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

Dim sourceSheet, targetSheet As Worksheet
Dim copyFromRange, copyToRange As Range
Dim Y As Range

Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("QC data")

For i = 0 To SQWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    Set sourceSheet = SQWorkbook.Worksheets(PCanalytes(i))
    Set Y = sourceSheet.Range("A7").End(xlDown)
    Set copyToRange = targetSheet.Range(PCanalytePositions(i))
    Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range(("H8"), Y.Offset(0, 7))
    Range(copyToRange) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(copyFromRange)
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect syntax!

Try this:

```
copyToRange.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(copyFromRange)
```

Why?, because you are telling Excel "copyToRange" is a RANGE already:

```
Dim copyFromRange, copyToRange As Range
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Thanks @r_student, that took care of the error I was getting. Now I'm realizing the cell references must be flawed somehow because the average I'm getting for this range aren't what I anticipated. What I'm trying to do is create a cell reference that is offset by 7 columns within the same row based on a variable starting row, hence the definition of Y in the code. What am I missing?

Comment: I realize what it is now, but I don't know how to fix it. I need to be able to describe two discrete cells for which to calculate an average from (in this case "H8" and 7 columns to the left of Y) and everything I've written is including all of the cells between them.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a range to get the average? as you said **H8 and 7 columns to the left** equals `Range("H8:A8")` right?

Comment: I need to be able to average the contents of H8 and the last cell in column H (using xlDown). Just those two cells without the contents of the cells from H9-Hn. Using "    Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range(H8:Y)" results in a syntax error

Comment: Check the Address of `Y` to see if the **Range** you're trying to `set` as `copyFromRange` is a valid **Range**, maybe you should try using `cells(rows,columns)` method, if you want to average the contents of H8 and last cell in column H this would be the syntax: `Range("H8", Range("H8").End(xlDown))`

Comment: When I use this " Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range(("H8"), (Range("H8").End(xlDown)))" I get an object defined error

Comment: Wrong syntax! Use this code: `Set copyFromRange = sourceSheet.Range("H8", Range("H8").End(xlDown))`